# Dropdown Panel is not vertically aligned to the Dropdown Textbox in Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am using `Angular`, `Angular Material` and `CSS`

I am trying to align the panel for the `mat-select` dropdown

```
<mat-select disableOptionCentering class="sort-portals" value="newest" panelClass="custom-panel-order-types">
    <mat-option value="newest">Newest</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="oldest">Oldest</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="ascending">Sort A to Z</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="descending">Sort Z to A</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

There are 2 classes for this - `sort-portals` and `custom-panel-order-types`

```
.sort-portals {
    background: $white;
    max-width: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding: 6px 6px 6px 11.5px;
}

.custom-panel-order-types {
  margin: 34px 0px !important;
  min-width: 150px !important;
}
```

The screenshot of the Dropdown is given below..

[image: Dropdown]

**EDIT**

The CSS of the Dropdown is given below..It is in the components `CSS` file. But the `custom-panel-order-types` is in `styles.scss` file...

```
.admin-header {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 18px;

    h2 {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .sort-portals {
         background: white;
         max-width: 150px;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-bottom: 0;
         padding: 6px 6px 6px 11.5px;
    }
}
```

Still with the Answer code, the panel is moving more to the left side.

How to align panel vertically to the Dropdown Textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are adding extra padding to the select that the dropdown is misaligned, you can just apply the padding that you applied on the select as margin on the dropdown, this will solve your issue!

```
.sort-portals {
  background: white;
  max-width: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 11.5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.custom-panel-order-types {
  min-width: 166px !important;
  margin: 34px 6px 34px 5px !important;
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hfwtg7?file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.scss) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`

Comment: Still it is not working.. Updated the Question with more details..

Comment: Still the panel is moving more and more to the left side of the Dropdown textbox with your new Answer.

Comment: @CPK_2011 inspect element the dropdown and try adjusting the values of margin till you get the correct answer, then you will be able to solve it!

Comment: Got the Answer. Because I am using `display: flex` in `.admin-header` it is causing this problem. When I remove `display: flex`, the Dropdown is moving to the left hand side of the page. How to move the Dropdown to the right of the page?

Comment: @CPK_2011 try adjusting the margins using inspect element and adjusting the CSS there

Comment: It is not problem with margins. Now when I remove `display: flex`, the whole `Dropdown` control is moving to the left of the page with correct alignment of panel to the Dropdown textbox. I would like to have it to the right of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256740/discussion-between-naren-murali-and-cpk-2011).